# How to filter and sort data from multiple microservices?

Tags: architecture, microservices

We have microservices which work with different, but related data. For example, ads and their stats. We want to be able to filter, sort and aggregate this related data for UI(and not only for it). For example, we want to show to a user ads which have 'car' in their text and which have more than 100 clicks.

**Challenges:**

- There could be a lot of data. Some users have millions of rows after filtration
- Services doesn't have all the data. For example, for statistics service ad without stats == non existent ad. It doesn't know anything about such ads. But sorting and filtration should work anyway(ad without stats should be considered as ad without zero clicks)

**Requirements:**

- Eventual consistency within couple of seconds is OK
- Data loss is not acceptable
- 5 to 10 seconds filtration and sorting for big clients with millions of rows is OK

**Solutions we could think of:**

- Load all data required by query from all services and filter and sort it in memory.
- Push updates from services to Elasticsearch(or something like this). Elastic handles query and returns ids of desired entities which then loaded from services.
- One big database for all services which has everything

What should we pay attention to? Are there other ways to solve our problem?

Answer (score 10):

You could use [CQRS](http://cqrs.nu/). In this low level architecture, the model use for writing data is split from the model use to read/query data. The write model is the canonical source of information, is the source of truth.

The write model publishes events that are interpreted/projected by one or more read models, in an eventually consistent manner. Those events could be even published in a message queue and consumed by external read models (other microservices). There is no 1:1 mapping from write to read. You can have 1 model for write and 3 models for read. Each read model is optimized for its use-case. This is the part that interests you: an speed-optimized read model.

An optimized read model has every thing it needs when it answers the queries. The data is fully denormalized (this means it needs no joins) and already indexed.

A read model can have its data sharded. You do this in order to minimize the collection size (a small collection is faster than a bigger one). In your case, you could shard by user: each user would have its own collection of statistics (i.e. a table in SQL or a document collection in NoSQL). You can use the build-in sharding of the database or you could shard it manually, by splitting in separate collections (tables).

> Services doesn't have all the data.

A read model could subscribe to many sources of truth (i.e. microservices or event streams).

One particular case that works very well with CQRS is Event sourcing; it has the advantage that you have the events from the begging of time, without the need to store them in a persistent message queue.

*P.S. I could not think about a use-case when a read model could not be made fast enough, given enough hardware resources.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's interesting approach and definitely could work. Although I'm not sure if my company is ready to go with cqrs right now.

Comment: Then you could use [CDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_data_capture) to generate the low-level change events and based on that you can maintain am optimized readmodel. CDC is also know as *poor man's event sourcing with CQRS*.

Comment: CQRS & Event Sourcing are a huge investment for a small company. Not only in terms of storage requirements, but also in implementation / maintenance complexity.

In case when you already have most of the services implemented, that would be a huge problem to "rewrite" them in an Event-Sourced way.

Also that enforces "CQRS / Event-Sourcing" as a low-level architecture, some would say that is considered an anti-pattern: https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/04/event-sourcing-anti-pattern.

In theory it seems like a great solution, but I am not sure that is worth the risk in this case.

Comment: @Anton I'm proposing CQRS, Event sourcing is listed in my answer only as a non-mandatory step forward. Also, please read my comment regarding CDC.

Comment: @Constantin I suppose that without event sourcing and an "asynchronous" method of updating read models you would need a sort-of back channel to rebuild the read models. Messages could be lost and tracking that could be a huge problem.

Comment: @Anton There is not 100% perfect solution that works in all cases but there are good-enough solutions. For example, you could have an Event-log build on top of a Message queue and publish the events to this Event-log in the same transaction as the Write model persistence.

Comment: @Constantin Yeah, there isn't. Just trying to understand trade-offs and potential problems

Comment: @Anton CQRS without Event sourcing forces you to use **transactions** and that affects write-side speed.

Comment: @Anton I recommend to you this book: https://developers.redhat.com/promotions/migrating-to-microservice-databases/

Answer (score 1):

Digging out the topic.

Imo. event sourcing can be overkill (it may require to rewrite part of application).

Why not create some kind of `query service` that collects and aggregates data required to sorting, filtering and pagination. It will just return ids in desired order and count.

Data can be collected using:

- Message queue (better performance but data can be inconsistent).
- Direct service calls (more consistent data but you have to be aware of performance loss - longer response time for services that writes to `query service`).

Comment: This could become a problem when you want to filter by fields from one database, and sort by fields from the other. E.g. filter 100K records by a field from database A and sort these by a field from database B.