# Microservices: Filtering across different services

Tags: architecture, microservices, distributed-system, distributed-transactions

In my current project, we have two micro services with two different DB instances which both have tables that **refer to the same underlying resource** (albeit named differently), that is, the resources table in service A's DB is called `foo` while in service B's DB it is called `bar`.

Writes are sent using both services and each service is responsible of writing to the other service on update/write/delete (ignoring network / DB failures for now.)

Each service is responsible for different information on the resource and thus each table contains **different columns** containing different information of the **same resource**. For example: service A has attribute `health_state` while service B has attribute [and column] `archived`.

We would like to allow the user to filter by both services columns / attributes - i.e. `GET /foo?search="health_state='unhealthy' and archived='false'"`. How would one go about doing that?

We had initially thought of having one micro service be the "frontend" to the other and support search in `A` for fields of both services. And then A would send the relevant search fields to `B` and join the results in `A`'s DB. This is one option that might not scale well if the result set of `B` is massive, this is because `A` requires **all** the `archived` resources (in the example above) in order to do the join. In addition the search query might be very complicated to parse. If **we do take this approach** are there any suggestions on how to do that **at scale**?

Keep in mind porting our application to something like CQRS as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48458627/how-to-filter-and-sort-data-from-multiple-microservices) seems like a massive change (there are currently 10K+ rows in the corresponding DB's).

Appreciate you're responses!

Comment: Why do you need two different services in the first place? Why don't you just have one microservice to manage the "resource"? If for some reason it is required CQRS approach could be the only option for you.

Comment: @cool I agree a monolith might be a good way to go. But this architecture was decided before I had joined the project.

Comment: If you have really scalability needs I would suggest you to combine them as data is still small (<100M) or move to CQRS. Former is better than latter in my opinion. There could be another alternative of creating another service for only search operation which is receiving data from other two services again like CQRS but this time it could be somehow simpler as it will be an edition than change. But I don't recommend to create a service for such operation.

Comment: Combine the two services or move to CQRS - I dont think both options are relevant for us right now.

Comment: Scalability should also be considered at UI. if you are showing all the records at one go on the UI, it seems a bad design on UI and it looks more like a report & if it's a report you should consider polling APIs to put the joined data in a cached db, keep refreshing it and use that a data source, however you need to consider how frequently you are going to update the cache.

Answer (score -2):

You could perhaps look at GraphQL. You can stitch the output of 2 different apps together to produce result. This is a pretty well known scalable solution and you can apply caching at graphql server as well to increase performance.

https://graphql.org/ is great starting point.

I would also suggest you relook at service design because filtering for the same resource should be typically done in the same service unless it is a channel service. If data can be accessed in near real time then indexing the data in elastic search and then retrieving is also another option.

Comment: Graphql part is misleading as it doesn't do any good for the actual problem.

Comment: why not? you can combine the output of both the API and apply filter.

Comment: What if the output of the first API returns 1 million rows?

Comment: I agree it could be a problem then but what if it does not? Hence I recommended relooking at design since CQRS seems to be a big change.  If attributes don't change frequently/no of records are less I think graphql with good caching strategy could work